# Anyway to install/uninstall firewall rules with batch script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Is there anyway to install/uninstall firewall rules with a batch script? If so, do you think you could point me in the right direction?

If it can't be done with a batch script, are there any other ways?

Any info is appreciated. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use NETSH. See

```
netsh advfirewall firewall /?
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I haven't tried it yet, but it seems to be just what I needed